# Hard boiled eggs cooked by a gentile

Tags: kashrut-kosher, bishul-akum

Are hard boiled eggs cooked by a gentile prohibited under the laws of Bishul Akum?

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this question. Your question was closed because this site is not a good place for personal questions. Those should be asked to a rabbi well-versed in the relevant laws who will ask questions on context and personal specifics to come to a good answer. This site can't substitute for this. Please don't let this deter you from coming back to learn with us.

Comment: Hard-boiled eggs remain subject to the issur of *bishul akum*, see https://oukosher.org/halacha-yomis/are-eggs-subject-to-the-prohibition-of-bishul-akum/ and https://consumer.crckosher.org/publications/hard-boiled-eggs/

Comment: Thank you. I did not know this was not the right type of question, and when I asked around it was a 'strange' enough question that I thought it could be appropriate here. I'll try to ask mroe appropriate questions--thank you.

Comment: Don't get it wrong. There is no right and wrong questions. It is just that personal questions are not a good format for us. Someone edited your question to personalize it and it makes a much better question now. Hope to see you back